# Action on algebraic variety and adjoint bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes, algebraic-groups, principal-bundles

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety and let $G$ be a complex algebraic group; I mean that $X$ is a reduced, separated scheme of finite type on $Spec\mathbb{C}$, and the underlying set of $G$ is a complex algebraic variety.

By action of $G$ on $X$, I mean a morphism $\alpha:X\times_{\mathbb{C}}G\to X$ of $\mathbb{C}$-schemes such that: for any $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $T$, one has that $\alpha(T):X(T)\times G(T)\to X(T)$ is an action of the group $G(T)$ on set $X(T)$; by this I can write $\alpha(T)(x,g)=x\cdot g$ without problems.

My doubt is: if I take a couple of points $x\in X$ and $g\in G$, has $\alpha(x,g)$ sense? I think no!, becasue in general $|X\times_{\mathbb{C}}G|$ is not in bijection with $|X|\times|G|$, as detailed in [Stacks Project](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JT).

In consequence, if $P$ is a principal $G$-bundle on $X$: how can I construct the adjoint bundle $Ad(P)$?

EDIT As usual in algebraic geometry: by princpal $G$-bundle $P$ on $X$ I mean a locally isotrival $G$-fibration $P$ on $X$, that is a $G$-fibration trival on an étale covering of $X$!

Comment: When going from differential geometry to algebraic geometry, the role of the underlying space (e.g. of a $G$-bundle) is replaced by the *functor of points* point of view. Thus, instead of trying to create some total space with certain properties, one would often construct a functor with certain properties. That is, try to construct the functor that $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$ should represent, and then ask whether this functor is indeed representable. Or if you're interested in the algebraic vector bundle $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$, then you could try to construct it étale-locally and use fpqc descent.

Comment: Maybe that was not very helpful for you, but unless I'm missing something, it seems that doing this construction algebraically might not be so easy without invoking the word 'descent' (some fancy form of glueing in a Grothendieck topology) at some point. The reason I say this is that a $G$-bundle is not always Zariski-locally trivial. However, should you want to construct $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$ as an *algebraic* vector bundle (locally free sheaf) using only the Zariski topology, you could try to figure out on which open sets it should be free, and then try to glue these free sheaves.

Comment: Don't worry Remy: I'm working in étale topology!

I'll try to work as you suggested in the first comment. :)

Thank you. ;)

Comment: Actually, after thinking about it, I realised that maybe you can do it directly in the Zariski topology. That is, try to see if you can directly write down what the module $\operatorname{Ad}(P)$ should be if you're on an affine base, even if you don't know a priori that it's locally free (you can always check that later). I'm not sure if this works, but a nice feature is that any principal $G$-bundle $P \to X$ is an affine morphism when the group $G$ is affine.